# Is last scattering surface synonymous to the size of the observable universe?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, cosmic-microwave-background

As far as I understand, the last scattering surface is that surface where the CMB photons last scattered. But isn't that same as the particle horizon or the *size* of the observable universe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless and until gravitational wave astronomy or neutrino astronomy become practical, yes. Everything about the the properties of the world beyond the surface of last scattering are inferred from what we observe inside and on the surface of last scattering.

Keep in mind, the surface of last scattering is expanding as our backward facing light cone encompasses more of the universe, even if the wavelength of the photons from that surface is getting longer and longer.

Comment: "_Keep in mind, the surface of the last scattering is expanding..._" same as saying that the size of the observable universe is increasing?

Comment: @SRS Depends. Your question here is ambiguous about the cause of the increase. There are two things going on: the space inside the surface of last scattering is expanding, and the area of intersection between our backwards facing light cone and the space-like hyper-surface called "recombination" or "the surface of last scattering" increases.